# Does rotating our hands reduce the possibility to fall?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, moment-of-inertia, stability

I was trying to balance on a thin wooden plank and when I was about to fall I would rotate my hands in vertical circles. I did not realize why I and other people I see trying not to fall on the plank would do such a motion.

By doing this do we reduce our possibility to fall? Knowing a little physics it would make sense to swing our hands in the opposite direction of rotation to reduce the torque produced by gravity instead of bringing them forward and increasing it.

Two reasons I could think of why we do this:

$\star$The inertia from our hands helps pull us back.

$\star$We try to push the air forwards and it would give an opposite push backward.

I understand this question is quite vague as I used a lot of "backward" and "forwards" and it would not make sense unless the situation is imagined the way I imagine it. If anything is unclear I will most definitely clarify.

Comment: I wonder if any gyroscopic effects could be at play

Answer (score -1):

Well, considering your body and your arms as one single system on the whole of which gravity is applying torque, we naturally tend to rotate our hands in the same sense as our "rotation of fall" so that maximum of the "change in angular momentum" that gravity gives, which is also in the same sense as the "rotation of fall", goes to the increase in rotation of our arms, and in the process the remaining of our body doesn't "rotate" much.
Ironically, if you rotate your arms opposite to the sense you fall, your body will have to fall even faster to make sure that the change in angular momentum due to gravity is conserved.
It is like, if gravity wants to give a +ve rotation, and you rotate your arms in a -ve sense, your body needs to have even more +ve rotation to cancel the extra negative of your arms, which isn't desirable. Therefore, we tend to rotate our arms in a +ve sense as well.

Comment: Don't we also rotate our arms in a +ve sense ?

Comment: Yes we do rotate our arms in a +ve sense, that's the point. I guess I wasn't clear in my explanation. Is my edit clear? @Glowingbluejuicebox

Comment: So if I was holding two fans with a very high rpm would I able to balance on the plank horizontally?

Comment: Its not just the RPM that matters, its the "rate of change of RPM". If you have control over the RPM, then by changing it properly, i think yes. But keeping in mind the difference in your body's inertia and that of the fan, the RPM change has to be tremendously high.